# Any verse in the Chaitanya Charitamrita where Chaitanya Mahaprabhu says that Srimad Bhagavatam is the greatest of all puranas?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, identification-request, chaitanya, chaitanya-charitamrita

(SB. 12:13:16)

> Just as the Gańgā is the greatest of all rivers, Lord Acyuta the supreme among deities and Lord Śambhu [Śiva] the greatest of Vaiṣṇavas, so Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam is the greatest of all Purāṇas.

The above verse is used my many Krishna-centric Vaishnavas to say that the Srimad Bhagavatam is the greatest of all the puranas. I have heard from many people that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu himself recommended this purana to all Vaishnavas. But is it mentioned in the Chaitanya Charitamrita that Mahaprabhu himself recommended this purana? Apologies to anyone offended by my question.

Comment: Visit this link [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) . Better formatting makes your posts more them readable. People may skip if the formatting is poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Chaitanya Mahaprabhu definitely recommended the Srimad Bhagavatam.  Here's what he says in [this chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/22/chapter-view) of the Chaitanya Charitamrita:

> One should associate with devotees, chant the holy name of the Lord, hear Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam, reside at Mathurā and worship the Deity with faith and veneration. These five limbs of devotional service are the best of all. Even a slight performance of these five awakens love for Kṛṣṇa.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is mentioned in [Chaitanya Charitamrita, Madhya Lila, Chapter-25, Verse-266](http://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/25/266), that Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam is preached by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

> śrī-bhāgavata-tattva-rasa karilā pracāre
>
> kṛṣṇa-tulya bhāgavata, jānāilā saṁsāre
>
> **Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu has personally preached the transcendental truths and mellows of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam**. Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam and the Supreme Personality of Godhead are identical, for Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam is the sound incarnation of Śrī Kṛṣṇa.